# makefile cannot run docker image with -w -v -u options

Tags: docker, makefile, workdir

I have working docker image that i can run locally by command

`docker run --rm -u $(id -u) -v${PWD}:${PWD} -w${PWD} protocbuilder:1.0 [other unimportant args]`

And everything works fine. I want use makefile to automate things using that container, so i created make command:

```
test:
    docker run --rm -u $(id -u) -v${PWD}:${PWD} -w${PWD} protocbuilder:1.0 [other unimportant args]
```

But when I call `make test` I'm getting following output:

```
docker run --rm -u  -v/Users/mikolaj/GolandProjects/project:/Users/mikolaj/GolandProjects/project -w/Users/mikolaj/GolandProjects/project protocbuilder:1.0 [other unimportant args]
docker: Error response from daemon: unable to find user -v/Users/mikolaj/GolandProjects/project: no matching entries in passwd file.
make: *** [test] Error 125
```

I'm not very into makefile things, so I don't understand why makefile fails with that when in standard call of `docker run` in console everything works fine. It seems that there is a problem with mapping user into container using `-u`, `-v` and `-w` arguments. Should I do some additional steps in makefile to make this work correctly? Or maybe I need to change something in `docker run` command inside makefile?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(...)` is (GNU) make function syntax.  If you need to include a literal `$` in a shell command for something like command substitution, you need to escape it by doubling the `$`

```makefile
test:
    docker run --rm -u $$(id -u) ...
    #                  ^^
```

You could also use the backtick syntax to avoid this escaping issue

```makefile
test:
    docker run --rm -u `id -u` ...
```

Similarly `${PWD}` gets expanded by make before the command gets run in the shell, but this probably isn't a significant difference.

Comment: Thanks, that solved a problem! I expected that this issue is much more complex, what a nice surprise :)

Comment: The simple rule for writing makefile recipes is (1) make it work at the shell prompt, (2) paste it into a make rule recipe, (3) replace all `$` that are in the shell command with `$$`, (4) profit!